# How to check language that is not in emulator?

Tags: android

I read, in Jelly Bean release they added Indic languages like kannada,telugu,malayalam. But i think these languages are not present in the Jelly Bean Emulator, so if i want to try any strings for any of these languages how can i achieve that? Precisely my question is , if the specific language is not present in Emulator how one can develop for those languages, is there any other way i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom font.
To use a custom font, do the following:
1. Find a font in the language you want, put it in the assets folder
2.

```
Typeface mFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "myFont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(mFont1);
```

To apply the font on all fields in the current view you can use:

```
    /**
 * Sets a selected font for all activity child views
 * @param activity
 * @param font
 */
public static void setFont(Activity activity,Typeface font) {
    setFont(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView(),font);
}

/**
 * Sets a selected font for current view and all its child views
 * @param activity
 * @param font
 */
public static void setFont(View view,Typeface font) {
    if (font == null || view == null)
        return;

    if (view instanceof TextView)
        ((TextView)view).setTypeface(font);

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            setFont(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i),font);
        }
    }
}
```